# Find two different records from the SQL Server table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to find all records in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table that have one ID but not another, but I'm struggling to design the query.

The table is `TransactionHistory` and it has a person column and a transaction type column. In this particular case there have been de-allocation transaction types without the allocation.

A working example would be an allocation of £1000, a sale of £100 and a de-allocation of £900. Not all person records are entitled to the allocation. 
The allocation `TransactionTypeID` has an ID of 167 and the de-allocation is 168. A query to return this would be:

```
select LineID, PersonID, TransactionTypeID 
from TransactionHistory 
where TransactionTypeID = 167
```

I need to find all records grouped by PersonID that have a `TransactionTypeID` of 168 without the `TransactionTypeID` of 167.

I've tried a CTE and joining the `TransactionHistory` table to itself I can't get the query correct.

Comment: Can you please share the table's structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to find all persons who have a de-allocation but not an allocation.  You can do this with `not in`:

```
--First get all records that have a de-allocation
SELECT LineID, PersonID, TransactionTypeID
FROM   TransactionHistory
WHERE  TransactionTypeID = 168
--Add not in clause to remove persons with that have an allocation record
AND    PersonID not in (SELECT PersonID
                        FROM   TransactionHistory
                        WHERE  TransactionTypeID = 167)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question.  Just let me know if that's the case.    I think you could do the same with to joins which have the transactiontypeid filter in the join.

```
select LineId, PersonID, TransactionType
from TransactionHistory t
Where  
   Exists( Select 1
      from TransactionHistory t2
      where t1.PersonId = t.PersonId
      and t1.LineId = t.LineId
      t2.TransactionTypeId = 167) 
and
   Not Exists (
      Select 1
      from TransactionHistory t1
      where t1.PersonId = t.PersonId
      and t1.LineId = t.LineId
      and t1.TransactionTypeId = 168)
```